# MySQL "backtrack" to get the first record in most recent "sequence"

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables: `customers` and `customers_history`.

Columns in each table:

`customers.id`, `customers.email`,

`customers_history.date`, `customers_history.user_id`, `customers_history.renewal_error`

I have an array of customer ID's who are currently in a `renewal_error` state: `$failing_customers_ids = array(10, 20);`

Example of records in `customers_history` for a customer:

`Date      user_id   renewal_error
28-03-17  10        Insufficient Funds
29-03-17  10        Insufficient Funds
30-03-17  10        NULL
31-03-17  10        Insufficient Funds
01-04-17  10        Insufficient Funds
31-03-17  20        Insufficient Funds
01-04-17  20        Insufficient Funds`

I need to query the customer's details such as email, and the date of first renewal error in the current failing sequence, so in this case, the query would result in:

`email: someEmailUserID10@example.com`, `date: 31-03-17`

`email: someEmaiUserID20l@example.com`, `date: 31-03-17`

I've tried joining the tables and then do the processing via PHP to "backtrack" and get what I want, but I am looking forward to see if I can achieve this all via MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

the query could be:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * from customers 
 join customers_history 
 on customers.id = customers_history.user_id
 where customers.id IN (:ids) 
 and customers_history.renewal_error = :error
 ORDER BY customers_history.date ASC"
```

Comment: There is actually no known error, I used only one error in my example but the error message is unknown (can be anything).

Comment: try to  run this query directly into phpmyadmin